# Can java make addition in the list of reserved words. Addition to the keywords in java

Tags: java, keyword

Well it looks like it is possible for JAVA creators to make new additions in reserved words for java i.e. keywords. Since java is so much verbose and applications across the world can be having variable names which might match with newly added keywords in java. What would be the impact of doing such a change at foundations of JAVA or let me generalize it for all languages.

Comment: 3 keywords have been added in 20 years, so it might happen. But it is always possible to specify the language version you are targeting when compiling a java program, so I guess the impact should not be too big.

Comment: @dotvav I know `enum` and `strictfp`. What's the other?

Comment: @PaulBoddington `assert` was added to Java 1.4 in 2002

Comment: Ah that's it. Thank you

Comment: yeah @dotvav that's what I thought too, it should come out as a software bug is it

Comment: they'll chose words that you'll never thinks of using as variable names :P

Comment: @ACV clearly `enum` and `assert` were in use :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to tell Java which version of the language is used with the `-source` parameter: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

> **-source release**
>   Specifies the version of source code accepted.

So it is possible for you to build a program with a Java 8 JSDK even if it is developed with the Java 1.4 language specification and you use the `enum` keyword. Nothing is broken, you just have to compile with `-source 1.4`.

Of course, if you need to migrate to a later version of Java in order to use some new language features, then you will have to refactor it and fix the compilation issues.

**Worth noticing** once compiled, the program should run with any newer version of Java. You may use a Java 7 SDK and compile some Java 1.4 code with `-source 1.4` and run it on a Java 5 or Java 8 JRE.

Comment: Yes, so basically if your program won't run with the new version you have the possibility to switch to use the old source

Comment: I found this in javac source code: `public boolean More ...allowEnums() {
        return compareTo(JDK1_5) >= 0;
   }` and then this method is called to see whether enums are allowed or not

Answer (score 0):

Yes oracle can make addition in list of java reserved keywords
as of 4 march 2019 there are :-
57 keywords, 55 are in use and 2 are not in use

List of keywords is :-

1. abstract
2. assert(added in 1.4)
3. boolean
4. break
5. byte
6. case
7. catch
8. char
9. class
10. continue
11. default
12. do
13. double
14. else
15. enum
16. exports (Java 9)
17. extends
18. final
19. finally
20. float
21. for
22. if
23. implements
24. import
25. instanceof
26. int
27. interface
28. long
29. module (Java 9)
30. native
31. new
32. package
33. private
34. protected
35. public
36. requires (Java 9)
37. return
38. short
39. static
40. strictfp
41. super
42. switch
43. synchronized
44. this
45. thow
46. throws
47. transient
48. try
49. void
50. volatile
51. while
52. true (literal)
53. null (literal)
54. false (literal)
55. var (since Java 10)
56. const (unused)
57. goto (unused)

4 new keywords which are added in java 9 and 10 are :- 
exports, module, requires and var